# Como tornar uma variável global jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tenho essa seguinte variável:

```
Site = {
   Alert: function(titulo, conteudo, data){
      var id = Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
   }
}
```

Gostaria de acessar ela em qualquer parte do meu código, especificamente aqui:

```
User = {
   ConfirmSair: function(){
      alert(id);
   }
}
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Em vêz de `var id` usa `window.id`, ou um nome mais seguro de não ser sobreescrito como `window.randomId`.

Esse tipo de programação é desaconselhado pois gera código difícil de manter, ler e é propício a sobre-escreveres essa variável noutro sitio do código e não sabes onde isso está a acontecer.

Mas se precisas fica a sugestão como indiquei em cima.

Comment: n funcionou essa sua forma ai.

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho podes explicar o que não funcionou? A minha sugestão só não funciona se não tiveres percebido a minha resposta. Mas se criares um exemplo que reproduza o teu problem a posso mostrar como pôr a funcionar.